# Deployment error in solidity while deploying ERC20 contract from OpenZeppelin

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I was creating an ERC20 contract using an open zeppelin code. I was trying to declare the initial supply for my tokens and mind the initial supply in a constructor as shown in the image below. Everything was compiled perfectly without any errors. But when I try to deploy the contract, I get the following error:

> creation of PJToken errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)

[image: Code]

I was trying to deploy my ERC20 contract, and was just trying to mint the total supply of tokens to my address.

Comment: Please add your code as code, not as images.

Comment: sure Tyler, I will take care of that.

Comment: The constructor uint should be provided in your deploy script as a string (BigNumber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who got the same kind of error, it was because inside the constructor I declared the integer which should be given as an input while you deploy the contract.
But I was not giving it any value during the deployment, and it showed the following error. When I tried giving it some value it worked fine.
Hope this helps anyone who faced this problem.